# ActiveResource posts instead of puts through application, but not command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeresource

I have an ActiveResource based application (referred to as client) that interfaces with an API application(referred to as api).

I have a model instance, I update the instance through a form, form puts to the client with a simple controller like this:

```
def update
  @current_user.update_attributes(:psset => params[:permissions])
end
```

Instead of going to the update controller on the api though, the update controller POSTS to the create controller on the api, not the update, i.e. triggers POST to /users instead PUT to /users/:id. the form always goes to this controller, so the form posts to the client properly.

The most maddening part is that running the command

```
@current_user.update_attributes(:psset => params[:permissions])
```

from within pry with the same environment for the same resource will PUT to /users/:id on the api.

So something in that update controller when calling update_attributes is catching that as trying to register a new resource and goes to create on the api.

I'm mystified as to why I can't update from a controller, but can from a command line instance. This is a first in this situation, with this controller, so there must be something I am doing at some point that triggers a new resource, but can't figure out what. As usual, I'll attempt to fill in more specific code based on questions. I know I'm probably just missing something dumb, but what?

EDIT: requested relevant routes

api:

```
   resources :users do       #, :only => [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
    collection do
    end
   end
```

client:

```
   resources :user, :only => [ :show, :update, :destroy ]
```

I'm realizing that earlier I made some distinction between user/users in routing and controllers on the client side that looking at I'm not sure is the most efficient method, now hmmm, but it has not been an issue until now. If there is a better way to make that distinction in routes (user/users) without separate controllers I'd like to now, it is just a persnickety user apprehension feature I noticed.

After tweaking routes around and whatnot, the issue persist. I post properly to the client route, that client route goes to create a new resource, not update the existing one (even though it uses params it would use for updating).

UGH, found an answer sort of. I started using the cached_resource gem with this client, and I recently turned it on for all the models. Turned it off for the user model, problem gone. Putting caching solutions to the future once more.

Comment: Routing problem?  Can you post the relevant snippet from your routes.rb file?  Alternatively it could be an issue in your view (in which case relevant source code would be helpful).

Comment: like @MarcTalbot said, it could be a routing or a view problem. You should post both if you can.

Comment: I checked the routes...on both sides, and they seem to be correct. Which side routes are you referring to checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic of activeresource update_attributes is next

> ## File activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb, line 1306
>
> ```
> def update_attributes(attributes)
>   load(attributes, false) && save
> end
> ```

```
# File activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb, line 1147
    def save
      new? ? create : update
    end
```

so it can post or put depends on result of new? method
here is that method (it depends on persisted)

## File activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb, line 1047

```
def new?
  !persisted?
end
```

Explanation is here
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-persisted-3F

Comment: This is interesting and most likely the root of the issue from my current understanding of how pieces work together. Removal of the cached_resource gem items for that particular model returned everything to fully functional, and I don't know enough yet about how that works in tune with this to say definitively.